# jQuery re-calculating totals and values but final total not right

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone have any ideas why the final total is not calculating correctly? it seems to be adding onto the value so like 249.00 + 9.00 is becoming 2499 rather than 258?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // set free shipping as false as default
  var isFree = "false";
  // Hide initial values that need updating
  $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").hide();
  // get current delivery rate
  $("#get_rate").trigger('click');
  // set a timeout and get total and shipping that was generated and add together for nnew total
  setTimeout(function(){
    // get cart sub-total
    var a = parseFloat($(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
    // get estimated shipping cost
    var b = parseFloat($("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
    if(b == "FREE"){
      b = "0.00"
      var isFree = "true";
    } else {
      b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/,'');
    }
    // add together sub-total and estimated shipping to new total
   var total = parseFloat(a + b).toFixed(2);
    //add the currency with £ (not sure why it was setting $ before)
    if(isFree == "true") {
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html("FREE");
    } else {
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html("£"+ b);
    }
    // update with new total with sub-total and added shipping
    $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total);
    // show new values
    $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").show();
  }, 2000);   
  $(".item-quantity input").on("change", function() {
     // let initially disable the input to avoid problems
     $(".item-quantity input").prop( "disabled", true );
     // gets auto get rates based on a UK address
     $("#get_rate").trigger('click');
     $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").hide();
     setTimeout(function(){
       var a = parseFloat($(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
       // get estimated shipping cost
    var b = parseFloat($("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
       if(b == "FREE"){
         b = "0.00"
         var isFree = "true";
       } else {
   b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, "");
       }
       // add together sub-total and estimated shipping to new total
       var total = parseFloat(a + b).toFixed(2);
       //add the currency with £ (not sure why it was setting $ before)
       if(isFree == "true") {
         $("#estimated-shipping em").html("FREE");
       } else {
         $("#estimated-shipping em").html("£"+ b);
       }
       // update with new total with sub-total and added shipping
       $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total);
       // update VAT when input changed
       var newVAT = (parseFloat($(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, "")) * 20) /100; 
       $(".cart-vat span").html("£"+ newVAT.toFixed(2));
       // show all new value updates
       $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").show();
       // lets enable the quantity input a gain
       $(".item-quantity input").prop( "disabled", false);
     }, 2000); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-right">


  <p class="cart-total">Sub-Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-vat">VAT 20% (included)<span class="money">£49.80</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-delivery">Delivery<span class="money" id="estimated-shipping">+ <em>$9.00</em></span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-finalTotal">Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <div class="cart-checkout">


    <button class="button button-primary button-add-to-cart button-pay-now" type="submit" name="checkout"><span class="icom-lock"></span>Pay Now</button>

    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
      <p>Or checkout with</p>
      <img id="applePayButton" style="display: none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="typeof createApplyPayButton === 'function' ? createApplyPayButton(this) : window.addEventListener('applePayReady', (function(){createApplyPayButton(this)}).bind(this))">
      <input type="image" name="goto_pp" value="paypal_express" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the line with `var total = parseFloat(a + b).toFixed(2);` and replace with `var total = (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)).toFixed(2);` as you need to parseFloat individual before process occured.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // set free shipping as false as default
  var isFree = "false";
  // Hide initial values that need updating
  $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").hide();
  // get current delivery rate
  $("#get_rate").trigger('click');
  // set a timeout and get total and shipping that was generated and add together for nnew total
  setTimeout(function(){
    // get cart sub-total
    var a = parseFloat($(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
    // get estimated shipping cost
    var b = parseFloat($("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
    if(b == "FREE"){
      b = "0.00"
      var isFree = "true";
    } else {
      b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/,'');
    }
    // add together sub-total and estimated shipping to new total
   var total = (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)).toFixed(2);
    //add the currency with £ (not sure why it was setting $ before)
    if(isFree == "true") {
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html("FREE");
    } else {
      $("#estimated-shipping em").html("£"+ b);
    }
    // update with new total with sub-total and added shipping
    $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total);
    // show new values
    $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").show();
  }, 2000);   
  $(".item-quantity input").on("change", function() {
     // let initially disable the input to avoid problems
     $(".item-quantity input").prop( "disabled", true );
     // gets auto get rates based on a UK address
     $("#get_rate").trigger('click');
     $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").hide();
     setTimeout(function(){
       var a = parseFloat($(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
       // get estimated shipping cost
    var b = parseFloat($("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, ""));
       if(b == "FREE"){
         b = "0.00"
         var isFree = "true";
       } else {
   b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, "");
       }
       console.log(a)
       // add together sub-total and estimated shipping to new total
       var total = (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)).toFixed(2);
       //add the currency with £ (not sure why it was setting $ before)
       if(isFree == "true") {
         $("#estimated-shipping em").html("FREE");
       } else {
         $("#estimated-shipping em").html("£"+ b);
       }
       // update with new total with sub-total and added shipping
       $('.cart-finalTotal span').html("£" + total);
       // update VAT when input changed
       var newVAT = (parseFloat($(".cart-total span").text().replace(/\$|£/gi, "")) * 20) /100; 
       $(".cart-vat span").html("£"+ newVAT.toFixed(2));
       // show all new value updates
       $("#estimated-shipping em, .cart-finalTotal span, .cart-vat span").show();
       // lets enable the quantity input a gain
       $(".item-quantity input").prop( "disabled", false);
     }, 2000); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-right">


  <p class="cart-total">Sub-Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-vat">VAT 20% (included)<span class="money">£49.80</span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-delivery">Delivery<span class="money" id="estimated-shipping">+ <em>$9.00</em></span>
  </p>
  <p class="cart-finalTotal">Total<span class="money">£249.00</span>
  </p>
  <div class="cart-checkout">


    <button class="button button-primary button-add-to-cart button-pay-now" type="submit" name="checkout"><span class="icom-lock"></span>Pay Now</button>

    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
      <p>Or checkout with</p>
      <img id="applePayButton" style="display: none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="typeof createApplyPayButton === 'function' ? createApplyPayButton(this) : window.addEventListener('applePayReady', (function(){createApplyPayButton(this)}).bind(this))">
      <input type="image" name="goto_pp" value="paypal_express" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work, only issue im having is when i change qty to like 6 i get NaN on total and if i set qty over 5 so like 6 then the vat is 0.20p and total sets as £1....

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, which part on code need to change?

Comment: I just get on integrated changes, if value goes above 1000 seems to set total to 1 and vat 20% of that which of course is 0.20... thinking maybe the toFixed 2

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `parseFloat` which causes some problems down the line. Change:

```
else {
  b = $("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/,'');
}
```

to

```
else {
  b = parseFloat($("#estimated-shipping em").text().replace(/\$|£/,''));
}
```

The actual problem happens in the line mentioned in the other answer.